# How can I get the last updated status on tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to write a bot, sometimes it seem that it create -sometimes- duplicated messages.

I am getting this error

```
{  
u'message': u'Status is a duplicate.', u'code': 187  
}
```

I need to verify if the last updated status is similar to the message I am going to write. Is there any way to extract the last update ? I was checking around but couldn't reach a solution, is there any pythonic tweepy guru around to give some hints ?

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple enough, For this first you need to extract the most recent tweets on your timeline, and also make sure that it is not a **RT** , for fetching your timeline, you can use :

```
api.user_timeline()
```

Which returns 20 latest posts from the user timeline at one time , Actually you can pass a parameter known as `page`(*default value 1*) as 1,2,3,4... if you want to fetch further posts. So we will fetch posts from the timeline until we reach post which is not a RT, Fetching the required post, we will check if it matches to your current post, so let's say your current post be:

```
new_post = "It's mourning Monday, mourn over the fun of Sunday."
def check_last_post(new_post):
    page_num = 1
    while True:
        timeline = api.user_timeline(page = page_num)
        for post in timeline:
            post = (post.text).encode('utf-8')
            if (not (post.startswith("RT"))):
                if not post == new_post:
                    print "Yes, I can update the status."
                    return True
                else:
                    print "Sorry the last post was the same!"
                    return False
        page_num+=1
```

So here is a function which returns a boolean value, `False` if the last post is same as the `new_post` and True otherwise, It will keep on searching user's timeline until a post is found, However if you are updating post regularly you will get the latest post in the page number 1 itself, but if you are doing a lot of retweets Then it will search for the further posts.

Comment: You can remove the print statements to clean up the console, it was just for debugging purposes.